# Calculate the probability select $k$ blue balls in box

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a box that contains 10 balls( 2 red balls and 8 blue balls). Probability select each ball is an uniform distribution. An event is defined that selects k balls $(0<k\le 10)$ from the box and then throw them into box.

1. What is probability select k balls that are blue balls?
2. Repeat it 100 times, How many times we choose k balls are blue balls?

That is my solution. However, I am not sure about my solution. Could you see help me?
Update: k  is known parameter. It follow a special distribution such as $\Omega(k)=0.2k^2 +0.3k^3 +0.5k^5$   that mean prob. select k=2 balls are 20%, k=3 balls are 30% and k=5 balls is 50% 
My solution: 
Prob. selection red balls are $$\frac {2}{10}=0.2$$
Prob. selection blue balls are $$\frac {8}{10}=0.8$$
Prob. selection k balls is
$$\frac {8 \choose k}{10 \choose k}$$

1. Prob. selection k balls that are blue balls is
   $$0.8 \times \frac {8 \choose k}{10 \choose k}$$
2. How many times choose k blue balls from 100 experiments
   $$100 \times 0.8 \times \frac {8 \choose k}{10 \choose k}$$
   [image]

Comment: Is $k$ an unknown constant between selections, or a uniformly distributed random variable realised on each trial?

Comment: $k$ is known parameter. It follow a special distribution such as $\Omega(k)=0.2k^2+0.3k^3+0.5k^5$ that mean prob. select k=2 balls are 20%, k=3 balls are 30% and k=5 balls is 50%

Comment: Well, include that information in the question!  Also whether $k$ is determined before the 100 trials (the same value used for all), or at each individual trial (each trial maybe a different value).

Comment: of course, k will be different via experiment. It is followed by $\Omega$ distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the (conditional) probability that all $k$ of the balls are selected from the blue is just: ${8\choose k}\big/{10\choose k}$, for $0\leq k\leq 8$ , and $0$ elsewhere.

That is, let $N_b$ be the number of blue balls selected, and $N_k$ the total number of balls selected, then:
$$\mathsf P(N_b=N_k\mid N_k=k) = \frac{8!/(8-k)!}{10!/(10-k)!} \mathbf 1_{k\in\{1\ldots 8\}}$$

As the number of balls selected is a **random variable** with the specified distribution, then the probability that all balls selected are blue is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(N_b=N_k) & =\frac{2}{10}\frac{8!\,(10-2)!}{(8-2)!\,10!}+\frac 3{10}\frac{8!\,(10-3)!}{(8-3)!\,10!}+\frac{5}{10}\frac{8!\,(10-5)!}{(8-5)!\,10!}
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac {74} {225}
\end{align}$$

And the expected number of occurrences of this event in 100 trials is $\dfrac{296}{9}$.

Comment: Great explanation